# Userform Find Previous Value returns blank values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a button that searches columns for data. If i press the next button, the following row with that filter will populate the textboxes and so on... But when i press the previous button, it just brings blanks cells. This happens only when is search by user ID and not by User Surname. Here is the code:

I tried with `Long`, which works on the next button but gives an error on previous button... i tried `string` and as i stated, it brings blank values...

```
Private Sub bsReg1_Click()
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim bRow As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim FindRow As Range

Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsm").Worksheets("Datos")

If Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" And Me.BApe3.Value = "" Then
lRow = Me.BApe3.Value
Set FindRow = Datos.Range("A:A").Find(What:=lRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Me.Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 13)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 9)

Else
bRow = Me.BApe3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=bRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 11)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)

End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub bsReg2_Click()
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim bRow As String
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsm").Worksheets("Datos")

If Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" And Me.BApe3.Value = "" Then

lRow = Me.BLeg3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("A:A").Find(What:=lRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Me.Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 13)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 9)

Else
bRow = Me.BApe3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=bRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 11)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: lrow = Me.Bape3.value ?

Comment: @CDP1802 It's the value stored from the username textbox

Comment: I found the error, i post the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: i didnt change the set lrow on the previous button and it was looking for the username textbox value. I change that and with setting the variable as: `Dim lRow As Long` works as a charm!

```
Private Sub bsReg1_Click()
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim bRow As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim FindRow As Range

Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Bonito\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsm").Worksheets("Datos")

If Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" And Me.BApe3.Value = "" Then
lRow = Me.BLeg3.Value
Set FindRow = Datos.Range("A:A").Find(What:=lRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Me.Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 13)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 9)

Else
bRow = Me.BApe3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=bRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 11)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)

End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```